# Mathematical induction Inequality

Tags: induction

There is a sequence S defined as follows:
$S_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$, $S_{n+1}=\frac{S_n}{1+\sqrt{1+S_n^2}}$ for all $n≥1.$

Let $t_n$ be the same recurrence as $S_n$ but with $t_1>\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, prove that $t_n>S_n$ for all $n≥1.$

I have tried to use mathematical induction, but I cannot figure out how to show $t_{n+1}>S_{n+1}$. Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We have $S_n>0$ for every $n$. Let $f(x)=\frac {x}{1+\sqrt {1+x^2}}.$ Show $x>y> 0\implies f(x)>f(y)$. Hence $t_n>S_n> 0\implies t_{n+1}=f(t_n)>f(S_n)=S_{n+1}.$....BTW I know a very easy way to show $x>y>0\implies f(x)>f(y)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show that $$0\lt S_n\lt t_n\Rightarrow S_{n+1}\lt t_{n+1}$$

You need to show that $$\frac{S_n}{1+\sqrt{1+S_n^2}}\lt \frac{t_n}{1+\sqrt{1+t_n^2}}$$
$$S_n+S_n\sqrt{1+t_n^2}\lt t_n+t_n\sqrt{1+S_n^2}$$

Since $S_n\lt t_n$, then is enough to show that
$$S_n\sqrt{1+t_n^2}\lt t_n\sqrt{1+S_n^2}|()^2$$

The inequality holds for positive numbers so square each side:

$$S_n^2+S_n^2t_n^2\lt t_n^2+S_n^2t_n^2$$
$$S_n^2\lt t_n^2$$
Which is true since $S_n\lt t_n$